# mod_rewrite for Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, rewrite

I'd like to rewrite /abc/abcd.png to /red/blue.php

How is that possible in Lighttpd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url.rewrite("^/abc/abcd.png$" => "/red/blue.php")

check out the lighttpd docs for more info http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite